# how do I see all embedded items via the console?

Tags: mongodb

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+(Reaching+into+Objects)

In the docs, all the samples use dot notation to find a particular item in a sub-collection of an object. How do I go about just getting the entire sub-collection? It seems simple but darned if I can find it in the docs.

All I really want to do is verify that sub-collections of an object are present via the `mongo` console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [$exists](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists) operator:

```
db.items.find( { embeddedArray : { $exists : true } } );
```

Above code will return all all documents that's have `embeddedArray` sub collection.